# Writing in SQLite multiple Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, sqlite

I've got a sqlite3 database and I want to write in it from multiple threads. I've got multiple ideas but I'm not sure which I should implement.

1. create multiple connection, detect and waif if the DB is locked
2. use one connection and try to make use of Serialized connections (which don't seem to be implemented in python)
3. have a background process with a single connection, which collects the queries from all threads and then executes them on their behalft
4. forget about SQlite and use something like Postgresql

What are the advances of these different approaches and which is most likely to be fruitful? Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

I used method 1 before. It is the easiest in coding. Since that project has a small website, each query take only several milliseconds. All the users requests can be processed promptly.

I also used method 3 before. Because when the query take longer time, it is better to queue the queries since frequent "detect and wait" makes no sense here. And would require a classic consumer-producer model. It would require more time to code.

But if the query is really heavy and frequent. I suggest look to other db like MS SQL/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlitedict
A lightweight wrapper around Python's sqlite3 database, with a dict-like interface and multi-thread access support.
But take into account "Concurrent requests are still serialized internally, so this "multithreaded support" doesn't give you any performance benefits. It is a work-around for sqlite limitations in Python."

PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. give you the better performance for several connections in one time